# Better management of cache objects of record data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

Is there a better way of doing this seems mundan to be retyping every var I think though automaper is to much for such a record however.

It works fine but I cant help but think could be neater I want to copy people cache also into the poi record

```
public POI FindPersonOrVessel(POI poiRecord ,int CaseId)
 {
   //each person that will be saved here will have a urn unique record number
   var findPersoninCache = _context.PeopleCache.Where(w => w.PersonUrn == poiRecord.Id);
   { 
       PeopleCache peopleCache =  new PeopleCache();
        peopleCache.FirstName = poiRecord.FirstName;
        peopleCache.LastName = poiRecord.LastName;
        peopleCache.DOB = poiRecord.DOB;
        peopleCache.Age = poiRecord.Age;
        peopleCache.Alias = peopleCache.Alias;
        peopleCache.MISObjectId = CaseId;
        peopleCache.FacialFeatures = poiRecord.FacialFeatures;
        peopleCache.PersonUrn = poiRecord.Id;
       _context.PeopleCache.Add(peopleCache);
       _context.SaveChanges();
       _toast.AddSuccessToastMessage("Saved Poi to Cache");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the copy function into it's own method (passing into it whatever objects u need), then call that method in findpersonorvessel. On the surface its neat, the "messy details" are encapsulated.